# Burning ATmega32 using USBasb

Tags: usb, burning, embedded-system

How to burn ATmega32 using USBasb. I am using atmega 32 for my project. I an using Ubuntu for many years but it is now one of the big problem for me.

Can we directly use terminal to burn atmega32 and which program can be used to create `hex` file.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. you can use the Atmel tools to compile your code:
http://www.atmel.com/tools/atmelavrtoolchainforlinux.aspx

And Avrdude (http://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/) to upload it via the USBasb. There is a cool tutorial here:
http://www.ladyada.net/learn/avr/avrdude.html
Ignore the fact that for some unfathomable reason they use windows - the commands and explanations are the same.